# Unit testing Asp.Net MVC routes: which approach to choose?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, routes

I'm new Asp.Net MVC and unit testing, so I apologize in advance if questions are somewhat stupid

When unit testing *incoming routes*, we must feed an URL into the *routing system* and verify that this URL is processed correctly.

1) But should the *routes* be tested separately ( thus a particular *unit test* would test no more than one route ) or should *all routes* be tested as a whole ( ie each *unit test* would test an instance returned by `RouteCollection.GetRouteData(...);` ) or both?

2) If the answer to **1)** is that *routes* should be tested as a whole, then I have trouble understanding how many URLs would we need to pass into the *routing system* to be sure it works correctly:

a) as far as I can tell, wouldn't we need to pass at least as many as many URLs as there are *registered routes*, where each of these URLs should be processed by a different *route* ( this way *all routes* would get the chance to process one URL )?

b) Should all URLs be tested within a *single unit test* or should we have *one unit test for each url*? If the latter, then wouldn't the number of *unit tests*  be the same as if each *unit test* would test no more than a *single route*?

c) Assuming we add a *new route* to the *routing system*, then we will most likely also need to *modify existing unit tests* in order for them to continue working properly, while if instead we were *testing routes separately*, then no modification of *existing unit tests* would be necessary?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with these kinds of test as you could easily end up testing the Asp.Net MVC code, which is something that Microsoft presumably does. (For example: wouldn't these tests be testing the functionality of the `GetRouteData` method?)

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, it sounds like you just want to make sure you're configuring the route data correctly.

I would consider this type of configuration code to be simply part of [creating your application's object graph](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), and not subject to unit testing. There are several reasons for this:

1. The configuration probably takes place in the composition root (e.g., within `Application_Start` in `global.asax`).
2. Any configuration initializes the system to a "technically correct" state. (Like if you replaced a production component with a [test double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Double). The system *works*; it just needs to be configured differently for production.)
3. It's very likely for these configurations to change in the future. For example, you mentioned that new routes could be added later. It's possible that existing routes may be changed, as well.
4. End-to-end/[Smoke testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_%28software%29) will make sure the application doesn't return a 404, which is usually what happens if the routing data is not configured properly.

---

After considering this, if you remain undeterred in testing the configuration then consider creating an abstraction that handles this configuration. That is, [create a seam](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=2) at the boundary where you are registering these routes.

This would allow you to mock out the calls to the Asp.Net MVC framework, and verify that you are sending it the expected configuration.